# Partial Hydration in Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, quasar-framework, hydration, astrojs

Lets say I have this simple structure as mounted Vue.js;

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Normally vue.js mounted on

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

as empty and renders it later. And I have the exact content of main div of that specific page as like this;

```
<div id="main">
    <p>this is the only content</p>
</div>
```

How can I partial hydrate the main div? Can I just send page like this;

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="main">
        <p>this is the only content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and mount vue on it? or what is the way here?
There won't be a node.js server in background.

Comment: For static content you can use astro itself. Partial hydration is for interactive components.

Comment: @saravanapriyan it seems what I was looking for was DOM Template Parsing Caveats: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats

Answer (score 1):

## Astro islands

Astro treats Frameworks like islands, each island is either fully hydrated or not. So what you can do is

- in a .astro component or page, include top level tags that you want to handle separately from the island you want to hydrate at a specific event
- split your code on multiple islands even if it is the same framework as long as they are included separately from a .astro file

### Example

here an example with 3 islands

```js
---
import MyVueComponent from '../components/MyVueComponent.vue';
---
<div id="custom">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <MyVueComponent client:visible />
    <MyVueComponent client:visible />
    <MyVueComponent client:visible />
</div>

<script>
//hydration happens first and independently from the Vue islands
</script>
```

Reference Astro doc https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/islands/